# Как описать instance Show для типа с параметром

Tags: типы, haskell

вот например, я захотел создать некоторый класс контейнеров, а потом захотел, чтобы все представители этого класса были ещё и представителями класса Show (в случае, когда значения внутри этого контейнера тоже Show). В попытках реализовать такое получил такой код:

```
class Container container where
    getList :: (container a) -> [a]

data Container1 b = One b | Many [b] | None

instance Container Container1 where
    getList None = []
    getList (Many xs) = xs
    getList (One x) = [x]

instance (Show a, Container c) => Show (c a) where 
    show = show. getList
```

И он не компилируется, намекая на FlexibleInstances. Объясните, пожалуйста, как решать такую проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что FlexibleInstances - это расширение языка, всё работает нормально, если применить это расширение и немного поправить код:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Container container where
    getList :: (container a) -> [a]

data Container1 b = One b | Many [b] | None

instance (Container c, Show a) => Show (c a) where
    show x = concatMap show $ getList x
```